# Sync Contact Groups with Outlook in SharePoint 2013 Contacts List

Tags: groups, outlook, contacts

My question is simple: Is it possible to sync groups of people with Outlook in SharePoint 2013, specifically in the Contacts list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not.

Sources:

- http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/14759/67949.aspx#67949
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2012/03/13/outlook-and-contacts-synchronization-what-s-about-contact-groups.aspx